# Issues with Dynamic Memory (_CrtIsValidHeapPointer)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am unsure as to why my program is seg. faulting every time I run it using the Visual Studio 2015 compiler, but compiles fine using the GNU Compiler. Can anyone provide insight into this issue?

This is usually included in a file called EVector.h, but I added it below incase it was needed

```
#include<iostream>

class EVector
{
public:
    EVector();
    ~EVector();

    //Operator Overloading
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, EVector&); //Input Stream
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, EVector&); //Output Stream
    EVector operator=(EVector&);

private:
    double* Tuples;
    int dimension;
};
```

This is my EVector.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>

EVector::EVector() {
    dimension = 0;
    Tuples = NULL;
}
```

This is how I usually delete my dynamic memory, but for some reason in this program it is causing segmentation faults (or at least Visual Studio thinks so)

```
EVector::~EVector() {
    if (Tuples != NULL) {
        delete[] Tuples;
    }
}
```

Rest of EVector.cpp

```
istream& operator>>(istream& instream, EVector& vector) {
    cout << "Enter the dimension of the Euclidian Vector: ";
    instream >> vector.dimension;

    vector.Tuples = new double[vector.dimension];
    cout << "Enter the Tuple's Values (The program will take values until all dimensions are full)" << endl;

    //Take in Tuples values
    for (int x = 0; x < vector.dimension; x++) {
        cout << "Enter a Value (" << (vector.dimension - x) << " value(s) left): ";
        instream >> vector.Tuples[x];
    }

    return instream;
}
```

I think it could have something to do with this function, it is my first time overloading the << and >> operands

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outstream, EVector& vector) {
    outstream << "Dimension: " << vector.dimension << endl;
    outstream << "Tuple's Values: ( ";
    for (int x = 0; x < vector.dimension; x++) {
        outstream << vector.Tuples[x] << " ";
    }
    outstream << ")";

    return outstream;
}
```

Deep copy function (required by my assignment spec)

```
EVector EVector::operator=(EVector& vector) {
    if (this == &vector) {
        return *this;
    }

    if (Tuples != NULL) {
        delete[] Tuples;
    }

    dimension = vector.dimension;
    Tuples = new double[dimension];

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        Tuples[i] = vector.Tuples[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a double delete. Your deep copy makes copies of your EVector elements.
But those contain a pointer.
If the destructor is called for both of those it will segfault.
Either invalidate the Toubles-pointer when copying, or do a true deepcopy and call an extra new[] for the allocation of the Tubles Pointer in the copied object.

Comment: No cigar. Thanks for the quick response. Any other possible ideas?

Comment: Oh no, stupid of me. Setting the pointer to NULL doesn't help, because there is a COPY of the element, which still containts a set pointer. Do a printf of the pointers address in the destructor and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Or invalidate the Tubles Pointer of the source in the deep copy.